# Find the mean, variance and others of a "RV = Gaussian RV + Discrete RV + "?

Tags: self-study, variance

Since I am solving a preparatory examen to study, it is not clear to me how to approach the question because **I don't know what is the specific topic to study rigorously in order to know how to do it**.

Here are the questions:

[image]
[image]

I know that since the RV are independent, then the means and variances add. μ=μ1+μ2 and σ2=σ21+σ22

But I'm just not sure on how to do it, in the begininng?, the questions for me are a bit unspecific.

**I would appreciate bibliographies (examples) over the topic because i don't know how to look for it specifically.**

Thank you

Comment: It seems that this Question needs a 'self-study' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment:** I will give a bit of help to get you started:

If $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2,$ then
$W = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ is standard normal with $E(W) = 0$ and $Var(W) = 1.$

The expectation of $Y$ is $E(Y) = (1/2)(-1) + (1/2)(1) = 0.$ Hence
$E(Z) = E(W + Y) = E(W) + E(Y) = 0.$ Now use your equation
$\sigma_Z^2 = \sigma_W^2 + \sigma_Y^2$ to find $Var(Z).$